# Synchronized code block

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety

Why do people "synchronize" for just 1 line of code? What is there to "synchronize"?

```
public final void addListener(Listener listener) {
  synchronized (listeners) {
    listeners.add(listener);
  }
}
```

EDIT: Thank you everyone. Very good answers to from all!

Comment: Why is (this) "one line of code" more atomic than 42 lines of code? Therein lies the reason ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`synchronized` on its own means that if multiple threads try to run this piece of code at the same time, only one of those threads is allowed inside the block at any given time. `synchronized (listeners)` uses `listeners` as a lock identifier, which means that this restriction applies to all blocks which synchronize on that variable - if one thread is inside one of those blocks, no other thread may enter any of them.

Even though there's only a single function call in a block, this can still make sense: that function consists of a lot of other instructions, and control may switch to a different thread while the first one is in the middle of that function. If the function is not *thread-safe*, that can cause problems, such as data getting overwritten.

In this particular case, the function call consists of adding a value to a collection `listeners`. While it's not impossible to make a thread-safe collection, most collections are not thread-safe for multiple writers. Thus, in order to ensure the collection does not get messed up, `synchronized` is needed.

EDIT: To give an example of how things may get messed up, assume this simplified implementation of `add`, where `length` is the number of elements in the `items` array:

```
public void Add(T item) {
  items[length++] = item;
}
```

That `length++` bit is not atomic; it consists of a read, an increment, and a write, and the thread can get interrupted after any of them. So, let's rewrite this a bit, to see what's really happening:

```
public void Add(T item) {
  int temp = length;
  length = length + 1;
  items[temp] = item;
}
```

Now assume two threads T1 and T2 enter Add at the same time. Here's one possible set of events:

```
T1: int temp = length;
T2: int temp = length;
T2: length = length + 1;
T2: items[temp] = item;
T1: length = length + 1;
T1: items[temp] = item;
```

The problem there is that *the same value* is used for `temp` by both threads, so the last thread to leave ends up overwriting the item that the first one put there; *and* there's an unassigned item at the very end.

It also doesn't help if `length` represented the next index to be used so we can use a preincrement:

```
public void Add(T item) {
  items[++length] = item;
}
```

Again, we rewrite this:

```
public void Add(T item) {
  length = length + 1;
  items[length] = item;
}
```

Now this is a possible sequence of events:

```
T1: length = length + 1;
T2: length = length + 1;
T2: items[length] = item;
T1: items[length] = item;
```

Once again, the last thread ends up overwriting the first, but now the unassigned item is the second-to-last item.

Comment: Not just _this_ piece of code, _any_ piece of code that syncs on `listeners`. The lock is on the object, not the code.

Comment: How could "the collection does not get messed up" if it didn't have "synchronized"? Can you explain any further on that? I'm almost there but don't quite get it to be on my own yet. Thank you.

Comment: @musselwhizzle: I've updated with a simple exmaple of how things can get messed up without synchronization.

Comment: Ok. very cool. I get that now. I suppose one final question. How do I know when I should make something synchronized? What should I consider?

Comment: @musselwhizzle: As a rule of thumb, any non-thread-safe piece of code which may be called by multiple threads is a *candidate* for `synchronized` (using a shared variable if it affects other code as well). Whether or not you should actually synchronize there is partially a judgment call; sometimes you don't *want* a piece of code to be aware of threads (e.g. this collection example), because `synchronized` is expensive. You will want to synchronize as late as possible, but not so late that it happens all the time.

Comment: @musselwhizzle: Also, there are times where you want to use something other than `synchronized`, but this is inherently a fairly advanced topic, so I suggest you read up on synchronization primitives if you want to know more about those options.

Answer (score 3):

It's because that "just 1 line of code" is nothing of the sort. It may be one line of source code in your file but the actual code running behind the scenes to achieve this may well be hundreds of instructions, *any* of which could be interrupted in a task switch.

By synchronising (here and anywhere else you wish to use `listeners` in some way), you guarantee that no other thread of execution will be able to pull the rug out from under you, or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

standard example:

```
count++;
```

this is expanded behind the scenes to

```
int tmp=count;
tmp=tmp+1;
count=tmp;
```

(this is because processors cannot operate directly on memory and has to load the variables into registers)

this has issues because between loading `count` and storing the updated result another thread could have updated it, this means that that update is lost leading to erroneous behavior

Answer (score 1):

In the example you provided, you are not only "synchronizing" one line of code but you are also locking the listeners object, preventing it from being accessed by other threads which also synchronize on the same object.

Assume you had another method on the class that contained addListener:

```
public void removeListener(Listener listener) {
   synchronized (listeners) {
       listeners.remove(listener);
   }
}
```

If thread T has locked the listeners object in a call to addListener, then thread S would have to wait on outside the synchronized block until thread T releases the lock on the listeners object. Then, it would acquire the lock, enter the synchronized block, and call listeners.remove(listener).

However, code which directly accessed the listeners object would not wait to acquire the lock.

```
public void unsafeRemoveListener(Listener listener) {
   listeners.remove(listener);
}
```

Comment: @zjs, please note that your [suggested improvement](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/117567), while improving this answer, changes the meaning of the post pretty significantly. [We discourage edits that drastically change the meaning of a question or answer](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit): _to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it_. I suggest making a new posting with your content, and once you get some up-votes, you can comment here. :)

Answer (score 0):

So you don't run into conflicts as multiple threads race through an app as the obvious answer.  With Ajax or Swing too you want to ensure the correct listener has the correct object it's listening for.

With some of the event handler toolkits I've worked with they abstract listeners off to managers so they don't have to do silly things like put all the listeners in an arrayList and then loop through to find the right match between the object and the listener for it.

I haven't done android yet, but I'm sure the concept is similar. Getting the wrong object for the listener is a problem.

HTH.